# Trying to set a UIImageView to a view

Tags: ios, uiview

My search View controller `searchVC` has a `UIImageView* backgroundImage`
I would like to set backgroundImage to be my view's image.
Why does this code not work ?

```
[searchVC.backgroundImage initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage.png"]];
[searchVC.view addSubview:searchVC.backgroundImage];
```

Comment: backgroundImage is a UIImageView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
//If backgroundImage is not created yet, create it.
searchVC.backgroundImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage.png"]] autorelease];

// If it is already created then you should just set the image
searchVC.backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage.png"];

[searchVC.view addSubview:searchVC.backgroundImage];
```

Comment: Ok cool, have a look at the answer now and let me know if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `searchVC.backgroundImage` a `frame`.  The `frame` tells the view where to be and how large it is.

Since you want it to act as a background image, try:

```
[searchVC.backgroundImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, searchVC.view.frame.size.width, searchVC.view.frame.size.height];
```

Also if `searchVC.view` has other subviews (as I imagine it will) make sure you add `searchVC.backgroundImage` as a subview before anything else, so it will go to the very back of the view.

Comment: I guess I am doing something wrong with the assigning of the view, because I just set the background Color to be red, and did not see that...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
searchVC.backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage.png"];

[searchVC.view addSubview:searchVC.backgroundImage];
```